# Text game, loop trouble

Tags: python

rules = input('Would you like to hear the rules? [Yes or No] ').tilte()

elif rules == 'No':

```
print('Good luck!')
```

else:

```
print("Invalid input.")
```

"i edit if elif else and i add title() cause can user enter lower case or upper and will give you Invalid input. You can try it "

Comment: `if rules == 'No'` This should be `elif`, not `if`.

Comment: Your while loop is only around the last `input(rules)`, so it only repeats that section. You need to either enclose the entirety of it in a while loop or use the while loop before the `if` statements to ensure you have the correct strings first. Also needing changes is using [elif instead of if - if](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Comment: `input(rules)` Also this doesn't assign to the `rules` variable, which was probably your intent...

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it! @JohnGordon, that was my intent and I fixed that by separating the loop from the Yes and No answers. Shorn, this was also very helpful, just a slip up with if/elif/else when trying to figure it out.